# i want to extract fractional part from a given double variable with exact precision.I m getting only upto 6 precision

Tags: c, type-conversion, int64

I'm trying to run this. I have tried fmod too. Nothing worked yet.

```
void main(){
    double a = 123.46566662;
    double frac = a - (long)a;
    printf("%f", frac);
}
//tried int64_t too   
// output is :.465667
```

Comment: Did you try changing the precision of `printf`? Like `%.10f`?

Comment: thanks it worked.any idea why it is not working without .10?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.10f` or `.nf` precision to get the desired precision. here `n` = number of precision.
thanks to **@StoryTeller**

```
void main()  
{      
double a=123.46566662;  
double frac=a-(long)a;  
printf("%.10f",frac);  
} 

//output :.4656666200
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of "exact precision" is what gets your. Decimal fractions (generally) cannot be represented in a finite binary number. Much like there's no "exact" decimal fraction for a 2/3.

The best you can hope for is to have a "close enough" fractional part with an ever-higher precision based on your data type (think `float` vs. `double`).

If you do indeed **have to** get the "exact precision" I recommend you implement your own "precise" arithmetic, in which you store decimal numbers in decimal representation. Be it a string, a [BCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), or an array of digits.